# Cannot Load My Custom WebEvent Provider

Tags: web-config, asp.net-2.0, provider, health-monitoring

In the App_Code folder in my ASP.NET 2.0 Web Site, I have a custom webeventprovider that inherits from BufferedWebEventProvider -

```
public class MyCustomEventProvider : BufferedWebEventProvider
{
  public override void ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void ProcessEventFlush(WebEventBufferFlushInfo flushInfo)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

In my web.config, I have the following -

```
<healthMonitoring>
<rules>
<add name="AllErrors" eventName="All Errors" provider="MyProvider" />
</rules>
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="MyProvider" type="MyCustomEventProvider" buffer="false" />
</providers>
</healthMonitoring>
```

When I try to build my web site, VS 2005 comes back with an error stating that it "Could not load type 'MyCustomEventProvider'".  What am I doing wrong that is causing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And it looks like I cannot have the source code for the custom WebEventProvider in the App_Code folder.  Thanks to [this blog](http://www.yaldex.com/asp_net_tutorial/html/6b527e89-94f2-42e4-8c03-1e27dec7f4e4.htm) post for that answer

> "Put the assembly containing the custom provider implementation in the
>   application's Bin subdirectory. You cannot put the provider source
>   code file in the App_Code subdirectory, because the health monitoring
>   system is configured and instantiated before any code files in the
>   App_Code subdirectory are compiled."